# I have two SELECT queries. Is it possible to merge them and get the results I am looking for?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SELECT queries, first is as follows:

```
SELECT u.Table_Name AS Tables, COUNT(*) AS ColumnCount
FROM User_Tab_Columns u
GROUP BY u.Table_Name;
```

Which gives me:

```
TABLES                         COLUMNCOUNT
------------------------------ -----------
DEPT                                     3
DUMMY                                    1
EMP                                      8
BONUS                                    4
SALGRADE                                 3
```

And the second query:

```
SELECT 'Emp' AS Tables, COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Emp
UNION
SELECT 'Dept', COUNT(*) FROM Dept
UNION
SELECT 'Salgrade', COUNT(*) FROM Salgrade
UNION
SELECT 'Dummy', COUNT(*) FROM Dummy
UNION
SELECT 'Bonus', COUNT(*) FROM Bonus;
```

Which gives me:

```
TABLES     ROWCOUNT
-------- ----------
Bonus             0
Dept              4
Dummy             1
Emp              14
Salgrade          5
```

I need help with writing a single query which will give me something looking like the following:

```
TABLES   COLUMNCOUNT ROWCOUNT
-------- ----------- --------
Bonus              4        0
Dept               3        4
Dummy              1        1
Emp                8       14
Salgrade           3        5
```

And I'm completely stuck in a rut about it. If someone could show me the right path, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.Tables,
       ColumnCount,
       ROWCOUNT
FROM   (SELECT u.Table_Name AS Tables,
               Count(*)     AS ColumnCount
        FROM   User_Tab_Columns u
        GROUP  BY u.Table_Name) A
       JOIN (SELECT 'Emp'    AS Tables,Count(*) AS ROWCOUNT
             FROM   Emp
             UNION
             SELECT 'Dept',Count(*)
             FROM   Dept
             UNION
             SELECT 'Salgrade', Count(*)
             FROM   Salgrade
             UNION
             SELECT 'Dummy',Count(*)
             FROM   Dummy
             UNION
             SELECT 'Bonus',Count(*)
             FROM   Bonus) B
         ON lower(a.Tables) = lower(b.Tables)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get the following message: `[ROWCOUNT]
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: @ShaunKelly01 - check now

Comment: `no rows selected` is what I'm given.

Comment: @ShaunKelly01 - may be because of `Upper case` in `columnCount` table. Used `Lower` function try now.

Comment: Good eye. It worked like a charm! Exactly as I wanted it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use "With" keyword in select and use it in query
So in your case:

```
WITH 
tempTable1 AS
  ( SELECT u.Table_Name AS Tables, COUNT(*) AS ColumnCount
   FROM User_Tab_Columns u
   GROUP BY u.Table_Name),
tempTable2 AS
  (SELECT 'Emp' AS Tables,
          COUNT(*) AS RowCount
   FROM Emp
   UNION SELECT 'Dept', COUNT(*)
   FROM Dept
   UNION SELECT 'Salgrade', COUNT(*)
   FROM Salgrade
   UNION SELECT 'Dummy', COUNT(*)
   FROM Dummy
   UNION SELECT 'Bonus', COUNT(*)
   FROM Bonus)
SELECT *
FROM tempTable1,
     tempTable2
WHERE tempTable1.tables = tempTable2.tables;
```

I don't have access to an Oracle DB right now to check the syntax and output, but this should give you a basic idea. You can find more information [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I input your query, but it came back with this: `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name`

Comment: @ShaunKelly01 I wrote the query from memory, so perhaps there is a syntax error. Did you take a look at the link in the answer? Essentially WITH is used in the following manner: 
`WITH 
subquery_name
AS
(the aggregation SQL statement)
SELECT
(query naming subquery_name);`

Comment: The `(` immediately after `WITH` and the matching `)` later on need to be removed.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for the hint! I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley is correct. Just want to clarify you mean `User_Tab_Columns` and not `user_tab_cols`.

Comment: @mmmmmpie I copied the queries as given by the OP to demonstrate the WITH clause.

Comment: @ShaunKelly01 There can be multiple ways of solving your problem. The other answer uses inline views, mine uses WITH clause, if your data volume is large/queries are complex/there is a need for re-use you can also consider creating views/materialized views and querying them. 
You will find plenty of help on the internet, for e.x. here is one on WITH vs. Inline view http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/subquery-factoring-4/

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between using inline views and using the WITH clause? Benefits/downsides to either?

Comment: @ShaunKelly01 in a simple usecase, both perform the same, the rule I try to follow is find out the reusability of the query, if it is just once then I too like inline views, with is useful if you are using the same inline view multiple times in the same query, but if the reusability/cost/complexity of the inline view is very high, I prefer to create a view. There is also a factor of maintainability and readability, it is easier to read and comment the with clause IMHO.